# SiC rectifier Q value vs capacitance

Tags: bridge-rectifier

I am choosing between schottky for a bridge rectifiers. But I can understand how to choose a SiC based on the parameters for a rectifier application.

I want the fastest 2A SiC diode (for lowest noise). Should I look for a diode with the lowest Qc or should I look for a diode with the lowest capacitance ? or the lowest Ir ?

- Cree 3D02060F
  https://www.mouser.fr/datasheet/2/90/3d02060f-838501.pdf
- Infineon IDH02G65C5XKSA2
  https://www.mouser.fr/datasheet/2/196/Infineon-IDH02G65C5-DS-v02_02-en-1225779.pdf
- Cree C4D02120A https://www.mouser.fr/datasheet/2/90/4d02120a-838539.pdf

Can you explain this to me please, I have read a lot of whitepapers but it is still blurry.
Thank you.

EDIT : it's for a bridge rectifier for an SMPS power supply for audio equipment (compressor/limiter). I don't have a circuit yet I am just wanting to build a simple SMPS based around the Infineon IR2153. This the stuff I have in mind ; https://homemade-circuits.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/smps2B3002Bwatt2Baudio2Bamp2Bpower2Bsupply2Bcircuit.png

Comment: Without an application circuit and knowledge of signals (i.e. YOUR intended circuit and description) then choosing one diode over another is pointless.

Comment: Sorry it's for a bridge rectifier for an SMPS power supply for audio equipment (compressor/limiter).

Comment: The circuit is where?

Comment: _”I am choosing between schottky for a bridge rectifiers.”_ With only one choice, that should be easy.

Comment: Hi I don't have a circuit yet I am just wanting to build a simple SMPS based around the Infineon IR2153. This the stuff I have in mind ; https://homemade-circuits.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/smps2B3002Bwatt2Baudio2Bamp2Bpower2Bsupply2Bcircuit.png

Comment: If you want "the fastest possible", the transformer may be the speed-limiter. Or wiring inductance. In such cases, plan on using a Ground Plane.

Comment: If you are referring to the BA159 diode, note that [IR recommend](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/ir2153.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355c8c5fc16af) using the IRS2153D instead of the IR2153, and the former doesn't use a diode in that position.

Comment: Thanks. I was refering to diodes in general just to help me understanding the Qc.

Comment: For example. The C4D02120A is 11nC while the UJ3D1202TS is 12nC but the latter has a lot less Capacitance. The other one STPSC2H12D is 15.6nC with almost the same capacitance as the 11nC Cree.